# Cant get Key values in console log using WAMP

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, wamp

I have this directory set up in WAMP's directory `www`.

[image: directory]

Everything is running fine, except for the getJSON code. Is not returning the values from php. Any help will be very appreciated.

```
$.getJSON('php/json-data-students.php', function(data) {
console.log(data);
```

I also tried :

```
  $.getJSON('../php/json-data-students.php', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? If you navigate to `../php/json-data-students.php` does it throw any errors?

Comment: Whats your URL looks like?

Comment: Hi. From the     ../php/json-data-students.php  I get an error, and below the correct data.   [1]http://i.imgur.com/5j43VfV.jpg

Comment: And this is what I get from the console...[1]http://i.imgur.com/66oCYTC.jpg